# Magento2.2.2 SOAP API Create Partial Invoice

Tags: api, invoice, magento2.2.2, soap

Partial invoice doesn't seem to be working correctly for SOAP requests when multiple item has been ordered.

**POST URL:** http://dev.test.com/soap/all?services=salesInvoiceOrderV1

**SOAP BODY:**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:def="http://dev.test.com/soap/all?services=salesInvoiceOrderV1">
    <soap:Body>
        <def:salesInvoiceOrderV1ExecuteRequest>
            <orderId>95</orderId>
            <appendComment>true</appendComment>
            <arguments>
                <extension_attributes />
            </arguments>
            <capture>true</capture>
            <comment>
                <comment>string</comment>
                <extension_attributes />
                <is_visible_on_front>0</is_visible_on_front>
            </comment>
            <items>
                <item>
                    <extension_attributes />
                    <order_item_id>189</order_item_id>
                    <qty>1</qty>
                </item>
            </items>
            <notify>true</notify>
        </def:salesInvoiceOrderV1ExecuteRequest>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

The request returns Invoice id But in Backend Invoice Items are Empty.

Is there a Bug or something I'm doing it wrong ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I've found out by try and error that tags should be formed as camelCase like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:def="http://dev.test.com/soap/all?services=salesInvoiceOrderV1">
    <soap:Body>
        <def:salesInvoiceOrderV1ExecuteRequest>
            <orderId>95</orderId>
            <appendComment>true</appendComment>
            <arguments>
                <extensionAttributes />
            </arguments>
            <capture>true</capture>
            <comment>
                <comment>string</comment>
                <extensionAttributes />
                <isVisibleOnFront>0</isVisibleOnFront>
            </comment>
            <items>
                <item>
                    <extensionAttributes />
                    <orderItemId>189</orderItemId>
                    <qty>1</qty>
                </item>
            </items>
            <notify>true</notify>
        </def:salesInvoiceOrderV1ExecuteRequest>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

results are not great as it doesn't tell in the response that it should be camelCase as REST are using it with underscore one can just assume it's ok.

Sorted.:)